# I set up remote Hive postgres meta .. but while accessing , i get "DBS" table insert error (DDL is not matching)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore, hadoop3, spark-hive

Hive 3.1.3,
PG 12 - remote meta,
changed spark and hive site.xml
used schematool to populate default tables
USING oracle object storage as hadoop storage. I have replaced actual path with place holder

Note: I have hive and spark on same server. spark it works with external metastore but hive doesnt.

When i try to open hive from terminal i see below error. I am total confused on columns it refers in error vs in DBS table

Here CATALOG_NAME is not part of https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/sql/postgres/hive-schema-3.1.0.postgres.sql
how come code is referring different structure?

2023-08-05 09:30:21,188 INFO objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient: Setting endpoint to https://oracle_ojectstorage
2023-08-05 09:30:21,438 INFO jersey.JerseyHttpClientBuilder: Setting connector provider to ApacheConnectorProvider
2023-08-05 09:30:21,548 INFO store.BmcDataStore: Using upload configuration: UploadConfiguration(minimumLengthForMultipartUpload=128, lengthPerUploadPart=128, maxPartsForMultipartUpload=10000, enforceMd5BeforeUpload=false, enforceMd5BeforeMultipartUpload=false, allowMultipartUploads=true, allowParallelUploads=true, disableAutoAbort=false)
2023-08-05 09:30:21,551 INFO bmc.ClientRuntime: Using SDK: Oracle-JavaSDK/3.17.1
2023-08-05 09:30:21,551 INFO bmc.ClientRuntime: User agent set to: Oracle-JavaSDK/3.17.1 (Linux/3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64; Java/1.8.0_342; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/25.342-b07) Oracle-HDFS_Connector/3.3.4.1.2.0
2023-08-05 09:30:21,556 INFO store.BmcDataStore: Object metadata caching disabled
2023-08-05 09:30:21,556 INFO store.BmcDataStore: fs.oci.caching.object.parquet.enabled is disabled, setting parquet cache spec to 'maximumSize=0', which disables the cache
2023-08-05 09:30:21,557 INFO hdfs.BmcFilesystemImpl: Setting working directory to oci://path/user/user, and initialized uri to oci://path
2023-08-05 09:30:21,570 INFO hdfs.BmcFilesystem: Physically closing delegate for oci://path/
2023-08-05 09:30:21,598 WARN metastore.HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.commitTransaction(ObjectStore.java:766)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createDatabase(ObjectStore.java:954)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:97)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:753)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:771)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:540)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8678)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:169)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.newInstance(JavaUtils.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:4306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:4374)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:4354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4610)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:382)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.init(HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "DBS" ("DB_ID","CATALOG_NAME","DESC","DB_LOCATION_URI","NAME","OWNER_NAME","OWNER_TYPE") VALUES (256,'hive','Default Hive database','oci://path/','default','public','ROLE') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:133)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1.handleError(QueryExecutorImpl.java:419)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2004)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:360)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:1019)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:125)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.java:366)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.processConnectionStatement(SQLController.java:676)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.processStatementsForConnection(SQLController.java:644)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController$1.transactionFlushed(SQLController.java:731)
at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractManagedConnection.transactionFlushed(AbstractManagedConnection.java:89)
at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2.transactionFlushed(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:450)
at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.flush(TransactionImpl.java:210)
at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:274)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.commitTransaction(ObjectStore.java:766)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createDatabase(ObjectStore.java:954)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:97)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:753)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:771)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:540)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8678)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:169)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.newInstance(JavaUtils.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:4306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:4374)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:4354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4610)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:382)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.init(HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
2023-08-05 09:30:21,602 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database hive.default, returning NoSuchObjectException
2023-08-05 09:30:21,605 ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: Retrying HMSHandler after 2000 ms (attempt 1 of 10) with error: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.commitTransaction(ObjectStore.java:766)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createDatabase(ObjectStore.java:954)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:97)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:753)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:775)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:540)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8678)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:169)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.newInstance(JavaUtils.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:4306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:4374)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:4354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4610)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:442)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:382)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.init(HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

Comment: Please share full log stack

Comment: @Raid - Sorry.. now attached the full log

Comment: The error is likely from your postgres server.

Comment: Check with someone of below stack
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:133) 

 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1.handleError(QueryExecutorImpl.java:419) 

 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2004) 

 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:360) 

 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:1019)